# Invert bitwise shift operator / power of two

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have the following simple equation in my C# program to convert a number to a resulting value:

```
sectorSize = 1 << sectorShift;
```

Is there some sort of inverse operation that will allow me to go the other way as well?

```
sectorShift = ???
```

I know that you can implement a loop, but that's a little bit of an overkill. I've never had to do this before, so I have no idea and I can't find anything online about it. The equation I need only needs to produce valid results when sectorSize is a power of two; the rest of the domain can go to hell for all I care.

Comment: The inverse of << is >>? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: bitshifts would only ever give you power-of-two operations anyways. `<<` is left shift, `>>` is right shift.

Comment: @MattBurland not technically correct.  Inverse means "the function that undoes another".  Because of overlfow, this doesn't always hold in C#: `(Int32.MaxValue << 1) >> 1 != Int32.MaxValue`

Comment: @ChrisShain: Well yes, obviously. But you could say that about a lot of operations including addition/subtraction and multiplication/division.

Comment: @MattBurland: `sectorSize = 1 << sectorShift`; `sectorSize >> sectorShift = 1`. Maybe I used the wrong word, but I was trying to get a value for sectorShift given a value for sectorSize, instead of literally undoing the operation. In other words, `sectorSize >> ??? = 1`.

Comment: "I know that you can implement a loop, but that's a little bit of an overkill." How is doing something simple and understandable, clear and maintainable, overkill but doing something that you don't even understand not?

Comment: @Jason: I just thought that I was missing something obvious, using several statements (a loop) to "undo" what I can "do" in a single statement. (I have an irrational fear when it comes to this in programming. :) ) The fact that I don't know/understand what to do is irrelevant, because the point of asking questions is to discover/learn so at the end of the day, I *do* understand what to do and why.

Comment: @Matt Burland: No >> is not the inverse of <<. You're given f:sectorShift -> 1 << sectorShift. You want a map g:sectorSize -> g(sectorSize) such that g(1 << sectorShift) is sectorShift. That is not >>. It's logarithm.

Comment: @aboveyou00: This function is easy to compute: f(p,q) = pq where p, q are primes. This function is not: given n that is the product of two primes p and q, find p, q such that pq = n. Just because one way is easy does not mean the inverse is.

Comment: Unfortunately .net does not expose the BSR / BitscanReverse instruction. That's an assembly instruction that tells you the index of the highest set bit.

Comment: @Jason Disregarding overflow, `>>` is the inverse of `f(x) = x << a` but not of `f(x) = a << x`. I'd say a binary operator has two inverses, a left and a right inverse. `>>` is one of them, but not the one the OP wants.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I should have said "`>>` is not the inverse of `1 << sectorShift`" instead of the lazy "`>>` is not the inverse of `<<`." Of course, `<<` doesn't even have any inverse at all because `(x, y) -> x << y` is not injective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Logarithms. But since you don't want to do that, use a loop and/or lookup table.

Comment: A little more specific: x = 1 << n means x = 2^n. To get n from x you have to compute n = Log(x, 2).

Answer (score 11):

Here are five ways to do that in C.  Translating them to correct C# is left as an exercise. **Be extremely careful.**

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Frankly, I would personally always go with the loop. It is not clear to me why you believe that simple and obviously correct code is "overkill".

Comment: With loops one must be careful about the abort condition. The downward loop you linked does not suffer from such problems, but a loop that counts upwards and compares `1 << i` with the input, can break for large inputs.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yep. That's why I said *be extremely careful*. It is very easy to get bit twiddling wrong.